# Angular-oauth2-oidc loadDiscoveryDocument in POST

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I wanted to use `loadDiscoveryDocument` to get Token with out `Login` user name and password. But by using `loadDiscoveryDocument` it calling the endpoint in `GET` method, instead I wanted to call the endpoint in `HTTP POST Method`

I do not know how to set `REQUEST METHOD POST` for `loadDiscoveryDocument`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [OpenID Connect Discovery Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfigurationRequest) that recommends use of GET.

The discovery endpoint does not return tokens or other types of secret, and only describes other endpoints and security capabilities. Most providers don't support POST - any particular reason why you want to use it? I suspect that Angular is doing the standards based thing already.

To use POST you would need to first locate the endpoint for your provider and see if it supports that method. if this doesn't work you won't be able to use POST in your code.

```
curl -X POST https://login.mycompany.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Comment: My Backend developers providing API service with POST method for login. I,e from the app I will send the Client Id and Security Key to the End point using POST method then in the response I will get the OAUTH id. so I have to use POST method for getting OAUTH Id.